# Palindrome creator using javascript and recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, palindrome

I need to create a function that takes a number and returns palindrome of this number, by summing its reverse number. For example 312 + 213 = 525. But what's more important, I must use recursion in this situation.

And, for example, number 96 needs like 4 iterations to become 4884.

Comment: where is your specific problem with the task?

Comment: I just don't know how to write such functions. Just read about recursion and I am totally confused, and can't understand how to use recursion in this homework

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lychrel_number
long story short: U sum 96 + 69 = 165, 165 + 561 = 726, 726 + 627 = 1353, 1353 + 3531 = 4884

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strategy is already explained in other comments. Here is a sample recursive JS-implementation that accomplishes your goal:

```js
// Keeps recursively addding the reverse number until a palindrome
// number is obtained
function findPalindrome(num) {
    numStr = num.toString();
    revNumStr = numStr.split("").reverse().join("");
    if (numStr === revNumStr) { // True if palindrome
        return num;
    } else { // Recursive part
        return findPalindrome(num + parseInt(revNumStr))
    }
}

console.log(findPalindrome(312));
console.log(findPalindrome(213));
console.log(findPalindrome(96));
```

Comment: I would also like to add that if you're having trouble wrapping your head around how recursive functions work, try to go through a couple of concrete examples by hand. That helped me immensely when I had to learn it.

Comment: Thx a lot, I already spend this night trying to figure out how does it works on more simple tasks, but unfortunately, I guess I need more time. Thx again.

Answer (score 1):

You could

- get number
- convert number to string
- get an array of digits
- reverse the array
- join the array
- convert to number
- add to original number
- convert sum to string
- iterate string and check if the value from the beginning is equal to the one at the end

  - if true return with sum
  - if false call function again with sum **<-- This is the recursion part.**

Comment: Thx a lot, but unfortunately I need the code, in order to understand what's going on.

Comment: @WizardRew: Then write the code.  You have a template here.  If you get stuck, show us what you've done and where the problem is.